# Store information in the browser cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

I want to use the browser cache to store information. Currently, I'm using the library Locache but I'm new at this.

I have this code so far:

```
   $ ('. countd'). click (function () {

    himg var = $ ('# imgoferta'). attr ('src');
    hnombre var = $ ('# nomoferta'). html ();

  locache.set ("history", { 'himg' [himg], 'hnombre' [hnombre] })
```

And show the result:

```
 console.log (locache.get ("history"));

   Object {himg: Array[1], hnombre: Array[1]}
```

So far, so good.
I like print this information in a html 'li' and able to store more than two records and not replaced.

Comment: Just an idea - perhaps you'll be better off with HTML5 localStorage?
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use localStorage instead. Chrome and others also have syncStorage which syncs on all the users devices.